# What's the most notable production model bicycle ever?

Tags: history

I'm thinking to start collecting bicycles of the last 20 or so years that are special in a way or the other. What would be the one bicycle that should be in such a collection?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! Sorry I have had to close this question as I would have liked to have answered at length about my wonderful all steel Raleigh bikes. Unfortunately this question just does not fit what we do here, please don't be dis-heartened, but do read our FAQ and try again...

Answer (score 1):

What about the Schwinn from *Peewee's Big Adventure*? 
[Here is a pic of it from flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/21684795@N05/3227223652/)
[image]